# String Literal Pool

Tags: java, string, pool

Well, I've got such a code

```
String s = "hello";
String s2 = s + "world";
```

I know that variable **s** is stored in Java Heap in String Literal Pool. Also I know that variable **s2** is stored in Java Heap (because '+' in this example creates a new object). But my question is: will "world" be put into Pool or nothing will happen with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will. Wherever / Whenever , you have a String literal declared, it goes to pool obviously, regardless the usage of it.

Comment: Thank you. But can you attach the link, where I can read about this?)

Comment: @ТимМаркусенко "Because all of the information needed to dynamically resolve the symbolic references to classes, fields and methods at run-time is coded with string constants, the constant pool contains in fact the largest portion of an average class file, approximately 60%. In fact, this makes the constant pool an easy target for code manipulation issues. The byte code instructions themselves just make up 12%."    https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/manual.html Not sure if you want to learn more about bytecode and string storage in the constant pool...

Answer (score 0):

Since the `String` "world" does not exist in the pool, a new `String` object instantiates, then it is placed in the pool.

When we use double quotes to create a `String`, it first looks for `String` with same value in the `String` pool, if found it just returns the reference else it creates a new `String` in the pool and then returns the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, 's' and 's2' are just references while real objects are "Hello" and "world". This follows the concept specifying Strings are immutable while String references are not. So, Yes, as "world" is String object,apart from being a String literal, it will be stored in heap similar to hello. Also remember neither 's' nor 's2' will goto heap as being mutable String references.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 's' as variable in PerGen, 's2' as variable in Stack.
I mean that there values stored in Pool and simply in Heap respectively.